# Using spacebar to check a checkbox and focus to the next checkbox

Tags: asp.net, checkbox

I have a column of checkbox in templatefield within a gridview. As it sometimes can have lots of rows, plus it is also a requirement to check all the checkboxes. So it really becomes a hassle to keep clicking using a mouse.

Then, I was told that spacebar could also do the same job, just that it only could check/uncheck 1 at a time. Hence you would require to press tab key to focus onto the next checkbox. So I was thinking if there is a way to be able to check/uncheck, focus onto the next checkbox with just spacebar alone?

Answer (score 0):

If you change from CheckBoxField to using templated columns in the grid?

Then tab + space bar will work. And in fact tab key not only works (tab to next), but if you have say 3 check boxes on one line, and you click on the first check box. now  you can hit tab, and hit space bar - it toggess the check box. You can hit tab again, and now space bar checks/un-checks the next check box.

And EVEN better, you reach the end of that one grid row? Then tab moves to the next grid row. And your cursor JUMPS to the first non bound field.

So, say I have this markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table table-hover">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"    />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"      />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName"    />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City"              />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Province" HeaderText="Province"      />
    <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Active" HeaderText="Active"       />

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Has Baggage" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
       <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:CheckBox ID="Baggage" Checked='<%# Eval("HasBAggage") %>' runat="server" />
       </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>

     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Smoking" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:CheckBox ID="Smoking" Checked='<%# Eval("Smoking") %>' runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>

      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Balcony" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:CheckBox ID="Balcony" Checked='<%# Eval("Balcony") %>' runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

So, all the columns are bound fields, but the LAST 3 are templated controls (standard asp.net check boxes)

code to fill looks like:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid()
    End If

End Sub


Sub LoadGrid()

    Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT * from tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName",
                    New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4))

        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        GridView1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End Using

End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

So, in above, if I just hit tab, I will be on the first row. Tapping space bar will check first box (Has baggage). You now on Smoking - you can tap space bar, or hit tab (you now on balcony). And if you hit tab again, you move to the row right below, and since the first standard control from the template is teh check box, you be right on the row below.

No additional code is required here - it works that way RIGHT out of the box without any code on your part. the only trick is to use standard asp.net controls (inside of a template field) as opposed to using bound field (or bound checkbox).

Comment: I think I forget to mention(my mistake),  I only have 1 checkbox column.  Also, I want to ask, could I possibly have the spacebar to do not only check/uncheck the checkbox, but also be able to move to the next checkbox down the column. So meaning like when I click spacebar, it would check and move to the next checkbox/ uncheck and move to the next checkbox

Comment: Because right now I am using template field for my checkbox, and I can do what you mention in your post. However, I am looking to see if iIcan combine the spacebar and tab function together (Don ask me why, my boss wants it)